# Class path errors

Tags: java, mysql, classpath

I have created some 4 to 5 Java files.  They work well when I run using Netbeans or Eclipse, but when I try to run using command prompt I get some errors.

- I have put all my files in `jdk/bin` folder.
- I am using MySQL connector jar file - I have put that file in `jdk/bin` folder
- I have set my class path to `jdk/bin` folder

But I get errors like:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at Dbconnection.Dbconnect(Dbconnection.java:29)
    at fileoperation.parsefiles(fileoperation.java:63)
    at fileoperation.main(fileoperation.java:127)
```

Will anybody tell - where is the problem?

Comment: IF i dont put my source files in jdk/bin folder i come i can run them using command prompt. it vill give errors

Comment: i have run all files first using javac and java command separately.They run well but i got errors of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try running java and javac from command propmt, if they run properly its fine.
than Try this:

```
javac -cp /path to/your/mysql connector jar file/  MyProgram.java
java -cp  .;/path to/your/mysql connector jar file/ MyProgram
```

`cp` stands for  `classpath`

You can also add multiple jar files after -cp.

if they don't run i mean `java or javac not found` error comes up than add `java.exe` and `javac.exe` to your windows `environment variable`

Add `C:\jdk1.6.0_23\bin` which contains java.exe and javac.exe to your environment variable.

Comment: currently my class path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar is that fine basically i am not getting what should be the value for classpath

Comment: There's also this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: don't keep jar files in your jdk folder, but your cp will work just fine.

Comment: if you are using netbeans, netbeans automatically creates a jar file in your netbeans "dist folder" when you build and compile the project. So you can directly run that jar file from command propmt

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you have to do.

1.It is not a good idea to place source files in the jdk bin directory.so undo that.

2.create a folder say "apps" in your c:(hard disk) if you are using Windows.Exactly this way. C:\apps

3.Save all your source files in that apps folder.

4.Go to your environment variable and create a classpath variable under "user variables for ..."

Click on the new button, under variable name and type "classpath" (without the quotes)
under "variable value",supply the mysql connector/j driver exactly like this with the jar file at the end. C:\mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx\mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx-bin.jar(x marks the version number)

5.click ok.

6.Set the path for your jdk so that you don't keep setting it over and over each time you want to run your program.

C:\program files\java\jdk1.x.x\bin copy this address path from your windows explorer's address bar and put a semicolon (;) before pasting it in the path. You have to do this in your path system variables else,you will end doing this each tme you want to execute some codes.

```
cd\
cd apps (enter)
set classpath=(enter)
set path=c:\program files\java\jdk1.x.x\bin(enter)
javac ClassName.java(enter)
java ClassName(enter)
```

(Am so sure you don't want that all the time )
Now to compile,open your command prompt and change directory to your apps directory and type javac to test if your configs did work.You will get a list of the javac options.If you did then you are on the right track again.

open your jdbc code make sure these are rightly coded.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:portnumber/test","username","password");
```

compile and run your code again.
Let me know if this helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the directory in the classpath, you either need to specify "*.jar" under the directory, or specify each jar by name.

Comment: now i have set my classpath like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar is it ok???